# How to override date format in regional and language options?

Tags: windows-xp, date

In Windows XP, it's not possible to display the date format in **DD/MM/YYYY**, because it wasn't available in the **regional and language options**. The following image will illustrate my problem.

[image]

So I'm planning to override the default Short Date Format. But I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Change "Standards And Formats" to "English (United Kingdom)".

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to override the **date format according to your requirements** you can follow the following steps,

**Step:1**
Go to `Run` Command and type `regedit`.

[image]

**Step:2**

In the dialog box, expand `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, expand `International`, **double-click** `sShortDate`, and a modal window will appear. Here you can enter your **customized date format** to override the default.

[image]